# What does "a priori" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I would like to know what ***a priori*** means in the following sentence:

> In SLAM both the trajectory of the platform and the location of all landmarks are estimated on-line without the need for any ***a priori*** knowledge of location.

Does it mean "previous"?

Comment: It's "a priori." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori

Comment: @AlexB., thanks for the reply but I still can't correlate the definitions you provided with the meaning of the word in the aforementioned sentence that I provided.

Comment: @CroCo Did you notice thatthe page has a link to one for "a priori knowledge"?

Comment: This is an interesting question; for years I heard and wrote *a priori* and took it from context to mean: *prior to starting or beforehand* and this is what is meant most of the time I see it used.However when I looked it up in the dict., I was surprised to see that there was no such definition; the closest I could find was "known via deduction or by reason alone." But we see it used all the time when talking about fixed information provided as input, which I can only weakly argue actually fits this definition. It's misleading to simply point to a dictionary with no comment on current usage.

Comment: Why the topic is on hold? I've used the dictionary but I could't comprehend the meaning of it. The word was not clear to me due to the variety of meanings.

Comment: Then the next step is to post an excerpt of the definition, highlighting what confuses you. As it is currently written, the question (asking “What does _a priori_ mean?”) is **off-topic** as [answerable with a dictionary](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary) and will be closed.

Comment: Same as Jim said: Especially in mathematics, the meaning of "a priori" does often not match the quoted dictionary  meaning. If I need to make a decision, I first identify what courses of action are possible a priori, that is without evaluating them. Then I think about things, and choose a course of action that seems best. In mathematics, the "a priori" error in a calculation is an estimate for the error, without actually performing the calculation. "A posteriori" error is the error as determined after actually doing the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-priori):

> [image: Image quote of the entry for a priori in the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.]

Or to the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/a%20priori):

> [image: Image quote of the entry for a priori in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary]

Comment: so it doesn't mean always previous. It seems to me according to Longman dictionary it means previous; however, in Oxford Dictionary it means a predicted assumption.

Comment: If you combine both explanations, you can say `any a priori knowledge of location` means any knowledge of location based on previously known facts or experiences.

Comment: You could probably leave these links in a comment rather than placing images in an answer.  (The text is more accessible--not everyone can see images, so text should be preferred over images of text.)